# Simple Radio Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Trying to set a radio (yes or no) default (Yes) building a chrome extension...
Saw lots of other posts whit similar error

```
Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null
```

but the solutions:

```
 document.getElementById('Yes').checked = "checked";
```

didn't work for me.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Yest or No",
  "description": "Yes or No",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jQuery-v1.10.0.js", "script.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },   
  "permissions": [
        "tabs", 
        "http://*/*", 
        "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

Popup.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pt-br" lang="pt-br">
<head>
</head>
  <head>
    <title>Yes or No</title>
    <script src="jQuery-v1.10.0.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>    
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('Yes').setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
});
```

test.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="padding-top: 5px">            
  <span style="font-size:12px">
    <input type="radio" name="FotoPadrao" id="Yes" value="1"> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="FotoPadrao" id="No"  value="0"> No
  </span>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: so i need to add a content script?

Comment: You have not explained what you are actually trying to do. The only indication we have that you are wanting to interact with a webpage is a comment you made on [Nobody's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40320183/3773011) (there is nothing in the question). But, yes, if you want to interact with a webpage, you have to use a content script. If you are wanting to interact with your `browser_action` popup, then no, you do not use a content script.

Comment: Thanks... what i,m realy trying to do is read a yes or no radios from a web page and set it true on $( document ).ready event...

Comment: Then you will need to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) that is directly about that.  You should not edit this question to change it that significantly. Once you have an answer that addresses the question you wrote (what is in the question has nothing to do with a webpage), you should not change the question so significantly. If your question was unclear, you could clarify. But, in this case, your question is quite clear about being an attempt to set a radio button within a `browser_action` popup, even if that was not what you actually wanted.

Comment: Thank you much... updated... got it working...

Comment: I have reverted your edit for two reasons: 1) an answer should go in an Answer. If you find the solution yourself, you are *encouraged* to provide an Answer to your own Question. 2) The change you made was sufficient to invalidate [Nobody's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40320183/3773011). While you are encouraged to add clarification to your question, you should not change it into, effectively, a different question which invalidates answers which have already been provided. If you want, you are welcome to *also* [ask] a new question which better describes your real problem

Comment: If you desire, you can get the [text of the version you edited](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/861abcab-8b22-4db1-958a-6602c35b6dea/view-source), or [view that revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40319991/3).

Answer (score 0):

I'll jump straight to the answer; you need to add a radio button to your HTML, but first, let's go through your code.

Since you use jquery, there is no need to do document.getElementById, you can use the jquery selector

```
$("#radio").prop('checked',true);
```

This snippet will check a radio button for the id "radio".

The code you posted did not have an radio button and this is why you had an error : when getElementById tried to find your input, it did no detect it,  so it returned null. Javascript cannot change the attribute of a null object, so it throwed an exception, halting your code.

Here is a snippet of how it should have been :
https://jsfiddle.net/gctkhvm4/1/

I recommend you read up on HTML and jquery here :
http://www.w3schools.com/

It contains great ressources to get started

**Edit:** I updated the fiddle to take in account the missing html file
The problem might come from the fact that you're trying to set the id of an element not in the same file as the script

Comment: Im sory im using a test.html file...  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="padding-top: 5px">            
  <span style="font-size:12px">
    <input type="radio" name="FotoPadrao" id="Yes" value="1"> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="FotoPadrao" id="No"  value="0"> No
  </span>
</div>
</body>

Comment: Thanks... what i,m realy trying to do is read  a yes or no radios from a web page and set it true on $( document ).ready event...

Comment: I think the issue is that the test.html file does not have the script of the script.ks

Comment: it´s not suppose to have... my test is so simulate the real form i needed cheked...

Comment: Can you make the setup you have in jsfiddle? (just the script and the page) so I can see better what is wrong

Comment: i have the same set as you but at the extension cant load <script> tags... i might be misunderstanding how chrome extension works... gonna read some more aboout it...

Comment: @Marisco, If you are attempting to interact with a webpage, then you are going to need to use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). This is *significantly* different from what you have shown in your question. If you are wanting to use code within a `<script>` element that is in your popup, it is possible, but very inconvenient. Much better is to include a separate *.js* file using a `src` attribute, as you are already doing with your `<script src="script.js">`. There are multiple answered questions about doing so.

Answer (score -1):

I had to add pure java script in a content_scripts... code is updated.